# Safari not displaying text

Tags: macos, safari

I have a fresh Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) install, with every update available installed, on a iMac (2011). Safari (9.0) is acting up. Firefox is working just as it should.

I have tried the usual suspects, disk repair and deleting the cache to no avail. I have but a few apps installed, Logic X and a couple of other music apps, but the system is super fresh, it should not act up like this. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot comparing Safari with Firefox to illustrate the no text issue]

Comment: Does this problem occur with other websites as well?  What is your text encoding setting?  (View > Text Encoding...)

Comment: Yes, it does. One other observation: If i let the page load for like 5-10 minutes it will eventually show the text.

Comment: It was ISO Latin 1, but i tried UTF-8 as well; no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend clearing your font cache using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) and rebooting to clear things up.

Comment: I tried doing so, and indeed did the text retur, but it turns out it is a far more complicated problem. It turns out none of the macs in out office can access certain sites, like youtube and google. I guess there is some problem with our router that filters something it is not told to do.